# Rearranging numbers in array using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have tried rearranging numbers in array using pointers, I have actually achieved it but I ended up with a terrible looking code, I know that there probably is a better way of doing this but I can't figure it out. I just want your input on my code.
Also I know that names for my integers aren't the best so please don't judge me for that.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void Fill(int a[], int b) {
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
        *(a + i) = rand() % 100;
}
void Print(int a[], int b) {
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
        cout << *(a + i) << " ";
}
void swap(int a[], int b, int c[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        *(c + (b - i - 1)) = *(a + i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        *(a + i) = *(c + i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        cout << *(a + i) << " ";
    }
}
int main() {
    int hello1[10], goodbye[10];
    Fill(hello1, 10);
    Print(hello1, 10);
    cout << endl;
    swap(hello1, 10, goodbye);
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use indices, which are a much shorter form of the same thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For fixed size array prefer std::array**

You can then declare your arrays like this

```
std::array<int, 10> hello, goodbye;
```

**Avoid multiple declaration on a single line**

It makes the code harder to read and it's easy to miss a variable declaration, I prefere the following:

```
std::array<int, 10> hello;
std::array<int, 10> goodbye;
```

**filling the array**
The STL gets handy here, you can use std::generate which takes a range of iterator and a callback, for each value in the range it will call the function and assign the return to the value. Making it a perfect use with lambda.

```
std::generate(hello.begin(), hello.end(), []{return rand() % 100;});
```

And you should use C++11 random rather than rand();

**printing**
First let's see how to pass our array, since the type of the array depends on it's size we have to use a templated function

```
template<size_t size>
void print(const std::array<int, size>& array)
{
}
```

Easy! Now we know the size of the array and the function is easier to call:

```
print(hello);
```

For loop are awesome! Ranged for loop are even more awesome!!

```
for(int value : hello)
    std::cout << value << ' ';
```

Notice that the `using namespace std` is considered bad practice, a simple google search will tell you why.

**swapping**

No need to create a function,  you can again use an stl algorithm, std::reverse, it will reverse the sequence of value give

```
std::reverse(hello.begin(), hello.end());
```

And print your array again

```
print(hello);
```

Also you dont need goodbye anymore

**Conclusion**

At the end, it's all about knowing the tools available to you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

template<size_t size>
void print(const std::array<int, size>& array)
{
   for(int value : hello)
        std::cout << value << ' ';

    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 10> hello;
    std::generate(hello.begin(), hello.end(), []{return rand() % 100;});

    print(hello);
    std::reverse(hello.begin(), hello.end());
    print(hello);
}
```